# Instalar um app de autoria própria em um iPhone sem conta de desenvolvedor

Tags: ios, xcode, app

Como o jailbreak não é proibido acho que posso fazer essa pergunta aqui, existe com jailbreak ou alguma outra forma de se instalar um app desenvolvido por mim em um iPhone?

No caso o app é de automação que irá controlar alguns dispositivos.

Comment: Por que algumas pessoas acham que o assunto é *off-topic*?

Comment: é claramente *on-topic*

Comment: Está pergunta não é duplicata, também não está fora do escopo já que tem relacionamento direto com programação, a pergunta é clara e objetiva, não é uma pergunta ampla uma vez que é quase respondível com um sim ou não, se é sobre a existência ou não de alguma forma de fazer algo não tem como ser baseada em opinião... Antes de votar para fechar, avalie a pergunta, se localize no contexto da mesma, faça uma análise minima pelo menos... a SOpt agradece!

Comment: Só um comentário maldoso de minha parte. Tem dinheiro pra comprar o smartphone mais caro do mercado, mas não quer gastar com uma conta de desenvolvedor...

Comment: @Renan Pessoalmente penso ao contrário: Paguei o preço mais elevado do mercado por um smartphone e ainda tenho que pagar pela conta de programador? :P

Comment: @Zuul Vem pro mundo do Android ;) brincadeiras a parte, eu dei +1 a esta pergunta e favoritei. +1 pra sua excelente resposta também.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Sem Jailbreaking

Infelizmente não é possível.

Sem uma conta de programador paga, não tens os certificados necessários para preparar o teu dispositivos para a instalação da aplicação.

O termo utilizado na documentação é "[Code Signing](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933-CH1-CODE_SIGNING_IN_A_NUTSHELL-SIGNING_CERTIFICATES)" <sup>(Inglês)</sup> que essencialmente permite:

> 1) Running Your App on Device Thru Xcode
>   2) Testing Your Submission Build with Ad Hoc distribution
>   3) Submitting Your App to the App Store
>   4) Creating and Installing an Enterprise build for In-House distribution

Que traduzido:

> 1) Executar a aplicação no dispositivo através do Xcode
>   2) Testar o envio da aplicação através de uma [distribuição Ad Hoc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>
>   3) Enviar a aplicação para a App Store
>   4) Criar e instalar uma versão empresarial da aplicação para distribuição *In-House*

<sup>Referências [na resposta do @BoltClock♦](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4952845/352449) do SOEN e [na resposta do @grgarside](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/140420/24524) do Ask Different.</sup>

---

## Com Jailbreaking

Com Jailbreaking já será possível através de aplicações de terceiros. Para o caso, a mais popular é o [JailCoder](http://oneiros.altervista.org/jailcoder/):

> JailCoder is an easy-to-use tool that patches Xcode and your projects in order to let you install your apps directly on your device.
>   It includes a step-by-step guided process to the patching operations.

Que traduzido:

> JailCoder é uma ferramenta fácil de usar que aplica patch no Xcode e seus projetos, a fim de deixá-lo instalar seus aplicativos diretamente no seu dispositivo.
>   Ele inclui um processo para as operações de patching com instruções passo-a-passo.